# Confusion with Arraylists, and subclasses

Tags: java, arraylist

so im trying to create a game created by an arraylist of many different custom objects, blocks, basically a rectangle with extra methods, but im confused on what im doing wrong, because along with creating the object i need to create an object of the superclass to make the object of the subclass. As found from other answered questions. I am new to comp sci and nee a little assistance. thanks for the help in advance.So right now I am working on having all of the blocks created in the array list, so they will fill the JFrame. I want the JFrame to have each block created one after another, but where i am running into a problem is, it appears im only creating one, while i have a 'for' loop running to create 144.I realize the blocks wont line up correctly right now, but my objective is to have to game start up with the object dirt, to fill up the array list. the object dirt is a subclass within another superclass called block.
(i wrote out some of the code i was expecting to put in, but once i encountered this problem I stopped writing, so ignore those if and else if statements. THANKS!)

Problem: it is only creating one object, of which is block, not the object dirt.

```
public class MuthaLoad extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("MuthaLoad");
        window.setContentPane(new MuthaLoad());
        window.setSize(600,600);
        window.setLocation(100,100);
        window.setVisible(true);

}
    private int health=100;
    private int money=100;

    private ArrayList<block> blockWorld=new ArrayList<block>();
    private block block=new block(0,0);
    private int colum;

    public MuthaLoad(){
        for(int i=0;i<144;i++){
            int random=(int)Math.random()*100;
            blockWorld.add(block.new dirt(50*i,0));
            if(i<72){

            }
            else if(random<5){

            }
            else if(random<50){
                blockWorld.add(block.new dirt(50,0));
            }
        }
    }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for(int i=0;i<144;i++){
                blockWorld.get(i).draw(g);
            }


    }
```

}

Comment: The question and text are a little conffusing, could try to explain your problem a little more objectivly?

Comment: sure, give me a minute

Comment: What's the actual problem here?  What does your program do that you're not expecting it to?

Comment: i made it clearer, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't creating only one block, you are creating many blocks at the same position:

```
int random = (int)Math.random() * 100;
```

The problem is this:

```
(int)Math.random();
```

`Math#random` generates a number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). By casting to the data type `int` this value always gets truncated to 0. What you mean is this:

```
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
```

And you don't need a superclass to instantiate a subclass. I assume that your `dirt` class is an inner class like so:

```
class Block {
    class Dirt extends Block {
    }
}
```

And that's why you actually need the `block` to create a new `dirt`. Change it to a static nested class and you don't need it:

```
class Block {
    static class Dirt extends Block {
    }
}
```

Now you can create a `new Block.Dirt()`.

Or just make a new class altogether:

```
// Block.java
class Block {
}

// Dirt.java
class Dirt extends Block {
}
```

Lastly, the [Java code convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) is that all classes begin with an uppercase letter. So `block` should be `Block` and `dirt` should be `Dirt`. Variables begin with a lowercase letter.

```
Block block = new Block();
Dirt dirt = new Dirt();
```

Particularly on Stack Overflow you'll notice the code examples get highlighted based on this convention so following it makes your code easier to read for an extra reason.